# Allow formatting in tag wiki headers.

Tags: discussion, feature-request

(This might be stack generic so this might belong on meta.SO, but then again it might only be interesting to AU so...)

In my never ending quest to get more existing teams in Ubuntu to use Ask I am encouraging them to take ownership of their related tags. For example having the security team watching the security tag, etc. Here's what the security tag looks like:

[image]

Just like any other tag. Now, Kees went ahead and added information in the "about the security tag":

[image]

Some good info there. The problem is that it's buried in "about the security tag" bit. Would it be a good idea to allow some links in the tag description on the top level page of a tag?

Comment: Related answer from Stack Exchange developer on Meta Stack Overflow. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts/62218#62218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts/62218#62218) this appears intentional to keep the pages cleaner. (Thanks for the pointer moberley)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I mocked up. Basically allowing some links in the description of a tag might help point people to where they can get official support, etc. It should certainly be limited (I don't think having a ton of information there would be useful), but just something that allows a team to point people to contact information, etc.

[image]